# sparklyr multiple Databricks notebooks, second connections fails with org.apache.spark.SparkException: Missing Credential Scope

Tags: connection, databricks, sparklyr

## First Databricks notebook

After restart of the cluster this is working fine:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method="databricks")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

## Second Databricks notebook

The second notebook fails:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method="databricks")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)

Error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Missing Credential Scope. 
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSDriver$Manager.$anonfun$scope$1(UCSDriver.scala:103)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSDriver$Manager.scope(UCSDriver.scala:103)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSDriver$Manager.currentScope(UCSDriver.scala:97)
    at com.databricks.unity.UnityCredentialScope$.currentScope(UnityCredentialScope.scala:100)
```

For me it make no sense or do i have to set a diffremct configuration on the second connection?